# Opencv VideoWriter with Gstreamer backend produce low quality video file

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer

I am trying to write frames (cv::Mat) into a video file using cv::VideoWriter. I need maximum speed (latency should be minimum). So, I was trying to use Gstreamer with x264 encoding. I wrote the following code:

```c++
std::string command = "appsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! filesink location=output.mp4";
auto writer_ =
  cv::VideoWriter(command, cv::CAP_GSTREAMER, 0, frameRate_, cv::Size(frameWidth_, frameHeight_), true);
// frameRate_ = 25
// frameWidth_ = 1920
// frameHeight_ = 1080

//...
// for example
// auto frame = cv::Mat(cv::Size(1920, 1080), CV_8UC3, 0);

writer_.write(frame);
```

Everything works fine, but the output video has very low quality (not in terms of resolution, the resolution is still the same). The frames are pixelated. I have searched the Internet but could not find the reason why this is happening.

What can be the reason for this?

Suggestions on a faster video writing method (in OpenCV) are also appreciated!

Edit: I tried @Micka's suggestion and changed the bitrate (to >10000 to achieve the required quality) but the latency increased significantly. Is there a faster way to save videos without losing quality much?

Comment: Have a look at gstreamer parameters and test different bitrates etc. https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/system/amd64_deb50/os/usr/share/gtk-doc/html/gst-plugins-ugly-plugins-0.10/gst-plugins-ugly-plugins-x264enc.html

Comment: you could improve the question by adding a picture of the source data (using imwrite), and a picture of the decoded video (VLC screenshot function). best to use same or similar frames in the video.

Comment: @Micka Thanks for the comment. I tried your suggestion, and it looks like it worked. But it has become much slower (to achieve high enough quality). I'll try tuning other parameters too.

Comment: video encoding is quite expensive, but luckily GStreamer has a lot of hardware accelerated encoders. Maybe you can find an encoder chip in your system (most modern systems have) and use the right GStreamer modules for it.